# Is there a way to use the lag function and subtract from the first row in the assigned group until a value is reached before repeating the process?

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

For example if I have a dataset that looks like this

```
structure(list(ID = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 145, 145, 145, 
                      145, 145, 145), `Date Time` = structure(c(1663037145, 1663037160, 
                                                                1663040745, 1663042520, 1663043060, 1663372800, 1663373100, 1663376400, 
                                                                1663376460, 1663376940, 1663377780), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                                                ), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -11L))
```

The way I use the lag function is

```
df %>% 
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(diff=`Date Time`-lag(`Date Time`))
```

However it subtracts by the previous row. How do I make it subtract by the first row in the group until the value goes over 1 hour as in 3600 seconds? Please no hard code, assume some of these groups are 100s of rows or 1.

```
structure(list(ID = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 145, 145, 145, 
145, 145, 145), `Date Time` = structure(c(1663037145, 1663037160, 
1663040745, 1663042520, 1663043060, 1663372800, 1663373100, 1663376400, 
1663376460, 1663376940, 1663377780), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), diff = c(NA, 15, 3600, NA, 540, NA, 300, 3600, 
NA, 8, 1320)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: What should happen for rows where the Date time is more than 1 hour after that group's first Date time?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `lag` and `lead` is to allow you to access a known & fixed number of rows ahead or behind in the dataset.

I tried the following experiment, which used a dynamic number of rows:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(num_rows = n()) %>%
  arrange(`Date Time`) %>%
  mutate(first_dt = lag(`Date Time`, num_rows - 1))
```

But it errors as `lag` will only accept "a positive integer, not a vector". So you are going to need another method.

The following code finds the minimum date time for each ID:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(min_date_time = min(`Date Time`))
```

You can then manipulate using standard calculations:

```r
... %>%
  mutate(diff_from_start = `Date Time` - min_date_time)
```

If you want to roll across multiple rows, another option is to look at using `cumsum` or similar. For example, to produce a cumulative sum of differences.